# React Audio Player - transform error

Tags: reactjs

I added the react audio player using npm today.  All I get when I go to the screen where this is imported is a message that says:

TransformError: at react-audio-player/dist/bundle.js: Unknown plugin "react-hot-leader/babel" specified in react-audio-player/.babelrc at 0

Does anybody know what this means and how to fix it?  There is nothing on the web that explains what is going on here.

Thanks

Comment: Do you/they have a typo? "react-hot-leader/babel" -> "react-hot-loader/babel"

Comment: Sorry, the error is loader - not leader

Comment: Could you try this section?
https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/master/docs#migration-to-30

Comment: I just tried two fixes they suggest, but still get the error.  I even change the .bablerc so it now looks like this    

{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  
}

Comment: Try installing hot-loader manually? npm install --save react-hot-loader@next
If that doesn't help I'm unfortunately out of ideas :(

Comment: Ok..I  did that..still the error - now since this is using the audio component, I'm not sure if this warning is relevant:
npm WARN react-audio-player@0.5.0 requires a peer of react-dom@15.x but none was installed.

Thanks for trying to help...much appreciated